# How to send an xml in the body using postman

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman

I have the following webapi call

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("whatever")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Apply([FromBody]string application)
```

application is an xml as string

How do I send it in postman?

1. In postman it works if I set it to body
   [image]
2. the header I set it to content-Type - application/xml

But this only works if the parameter in the controller method is set to XElement.
As you can see above mine is a string, and this is always null.

Can I set a string as variable with inside as xml?
or How do pass an xml as string in postman ?

Many thanks

Comment: Pls post your xml file too, in order it could be tested

Comment: Any xml file will do . Cannot post xml file as I don't have one I was using a made up one